# sending money to different recipients paypal

Tags: android, ios, paypal

im new to the paypal-api-ios-android integration, and what i want to do with my app is the following....

I have a publicity app, where there is a lot of business registered (mostly wine producers), and what i want to do is to offer the possibility to the customer to make reservations for wine tasting using paypal to make the payment, but not using my paypal account, instead of that, each wine producer can receive the money directly to their accounts....

I don't know, if this is possible, if it is, any clue how or where should i start searching and how is this process named??

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This unfortunately not possible at this point. With Mobile Sdk 2.0 release, the only merchant who can get paid is the one with the client_id.

If you are looking to transfer funds to a receiver's PayPal account, your best bet might be Adaptive Payments (Send money) or Mass Pay

Comment: Sad to hear this, but thanks, i would take a look to that other options

Comment: if it answered your question now, would you mind accepting the answer so that someone coming in later would know that this is currently unfeasible?

Answer (score 0):

So peer to peer communication is not yet possible with Mobile Sdk 2.0, right?