# PayPal Mobile API, How Do I Do This?

Tags: ios, paypal, oauth

I'm somewhat familiar with the mobile PayPal api for iOS, but I'm a bit confused on a bit of functionality I'd like to integrate.

I'm working on an app where individuals can accept payments from others within the app, however I don't want the receivers of funds to have to provide the app with an application id / secret created from their applications section in the paypal developers section as it's overly complicated and a big barrier for the sake of what needs to be accomplished. The preferred way would be retrieving the access token / secret automatically for the user through an oauth style login - which I'm not able to find if paypal supports this, at least via mobile.

All I need, is to be able to setup a way for one paypal user to send payment to another paypal user within my application using PayPal's api, preferably without requiring the receiver to manually provide their id/secret tokens. Is this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's very possible.  PayPal's [Permissions API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsAbout/) uses OAuth to authentication 3rd party users of your app.  What you explained is exactly what it's for.

When users sign up for your app all they will have to do is click a button (or trigger the event of approving the app somehow) and then they will log in using their PayPal account, review the permissions they are approving for the app (which you setup in the API calls, of course) and Agree, which sends them right back into your app and passes the tokens you'll need back and forth accordingly.

Alternatively, you could provide instructions for people to Grant API Access to your app through their PayPal profile.  This is easier than explaining how to generate secret keys and all of that, but still not as easy as the Permissions integration would be for them.

Comment: Wait, so I'd be able to utilize the iOS PayPal Mobile SDK with the permissions API? I need to be able to direct payments to user X that has granted permission through the iOS mobile paypal system.

Comment: With the classic api approach, I'm assuming everything is tied through a master paypal account that gets the permissions to perform actions on others behalfs? What happens if this master account goes down? Is the whole service toast?

Additionally, is there any problem with providing users instructions within the app through a webview to create a REST app, allowing us to store their Client ID / Secret with their permission, and then using that approach instead? It seems much less code heavy, and the decentralization is much more attractive?

Comment: I've never used the iOS SDK specifically, but it's just a matter of API calls, so yeah, it should work just fine.  If the SDK doesn't have that built in you could build those calls yourself.  Yes, if the account the API credentials are pulled from goes down then the app won't work anymore.  If you're going go the route of instructions I would recommend just having them Grant API Permissions manually through their PayPal profile, which gives you the same access the Permissions API would.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [sending money to different recipients paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019939/sending-money-to-different-recipients-paypal/24040931#24040931) for the discussion, this is unfortunately not possible at this point, although it will likely be addressed in a future release. The separate id/secret approach would work with REST apis to allow for multiple receivers of payments, although it does add difficulty with implementation.

Comment: I think you're mistaken.  The Permissions API uses OAuth tokens to grant 3rd party access to users of hosted applications.